# Bidirectional BFS in Python Implementation

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, maze, bidirectional-search

I am implementing a bidirectional BFS for a 2d maze problem in Python 3.7.3.

Firstly, here is how I create the maze:

```
for row in range(dim):
    # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
    # in this row
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(dim):
        grid[row].append(np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, 1))  # Append a cell
        if (row == column == dim - 1):
            grid[row][column] = 0
    grid[0][0] = 0
```

Now, in order to facilitate the bidirectional BFS, I defined a **junct** class which is essentially a node which stores both a parent **junct** from the starting direction and a parent **junct** from the goal direction.

```
class junct():
    def __init__(self, row, column, parent_S, parent_G):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.parent_S = parent_S
        self.parent_G = parent_G

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.row == other.row and self.column == other.column)
```

Here is my bidirectional bfs function. It is part of an **Agent** class which has not given me any issues so far. I want this function to return a list of tuples **(row, column)** of all the nodes in the path from the start to the goal.

```
def bidirectional_bfs(self):
        def get_value(maze, a, b):
            return maze[a][b]
        def is_out_of_bounds(a, b, d):
            return (a < 0 or a >= dim) or (b < 0 or b >= d)

        grid = self.grid
        dim = len(grid)
        Q_start = []
        Q_goal = []
        visited = []
        start = junct(0, 0, None, None)
        goal = junct(dim-1, dim-1, None, None)
        Q_start.append(start)
        Q_goal.append(goal)
        visited.append(start)
        visited.append(goal)


        #beginning loop
        while (len(Q_start) > 0) and (len(Q_goal) > 0):
            #initializations
            current_S = Q_start[0]
            current_G = Q_goal[0]

            row_S = current_S.row
            column_S = current_S.column

            row_G = current_G.row
            column_G = current_G.column

            #some mechanics
            if len(Q_start) > 0:
                Q_start.pop(0)
            if len(Q_goal) > 0:
                Q_goal.pop(0)

            #in case the current node from starting is in the goal Queue
            if (current_S in Q_goal):
                #forming the path back to G
                current = current_S
                path_S = [current]
                while current.parent_S is not None:
                    path_S.append(current.parent_S)
                    current = current.parent_S
                path_S = [(item.row, item.column) for item in path_S]
                print(path_S)

             #in case the current node from goal is in the start Queue
            if (current_G in Q_start):
                #forming the path back to S
                current = current_G
                path_G = [currrent]
                while current.parent_S is not None:
                    path_G.append(current.parent_G)
                    current = current.parent_G
                path_G = [(item.row, item.column) for item in path_G]
                print(path_G)

            if (current_S in Q_goal) and (current_G in Q_start):
                path = [item for item in path_G for item in path_S]
                print(path)
                return path

            #enqueueing children from the start direction
            children_S = [junct(row_S+1, column_S, current_S, None), junct(row_S-1, column_S, current_S, None), junct(row_S, column_S+1, current_S, None), junct(row_S, column_S-1, current_S, None)]
            for child in children_S:
                if not is_out_of_bounds(child.row, child.column, dim):
                    if child not in visited:
                        if get_value(grid, child.row, child.column) == 0:
                            Q_start.append(child)
                            visited.append(child)

            #enqueueing childen from the goal direction
            #enqueueing children from the start direction
            children_G = [junct(row_G+1, column_G, None, current_G), junct(row_G-1, column_G, None, current_G), junct(row_G, column_G+1, None, current_G), junct(row_G, column_G-1, None, current_G)]
                for child in children_S:
                    if not is_out_of_bounds(child.row, child.column, dim):
                        if child not in visited:
                            if get_value(grid, child.row, child.column) == 0:
                                Q_goal.append(child)
                                visited.append(child)

        return []
        print("No path")
```

Where am I going wrong in my code? What needs to be changed in order to return the path?

Comment: Please specify what problem you are encountering and an example input for reproducing that problem.